# How to config client work with spring 2.4.1 and cloud 2020.0.0?

Tags: spring, cloud, config

I'm use spring boot new version 2.4.1 and spring cloud version 2020.0.0 . when I going to fetch from config server config client not fetch the config server.

Answer (score 0):

In release spring boot 2.4.1 They did some changes in Spring cloud

- spring cloud commons
- spring cloud contracts
- spring cloud functions

Spring cloud commons, In spring 2.4.1, Bootstrap has been disabled by default. The new way of importing configuration is via the new spring.config.import functionality provided by Spring Boot 2.4.1 . So cannot fetch config server with **spring.cloud.config.uri** in bootstrap.yml.

For fetch config server need to add **spring.config.import:optional:configserver:{your config server url}** as a property in application peroperties.
With this new release no need bootstrap.yml file like ealier.
more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/#config-first-bootstrap